# how to get rid of -- openssl error

Tags: openssl, embedded-linux

I have compiles & make install openssl. Just to check to check that package is installed correctly i run following program. It compiled & run correctly for me. `Means openssl is installed correctly` & is not broken.

```
#include <openssl/engine.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

int main(int c, char **v)
{
    ERR_load_crypto_strings();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    ENGINE_load_builtin_engines();
    ENGINE_register_all_complete();
    puts("Stuff seems okay.");
    return 0;
}
(It build okay with "gcc -Wall -lcrypto test.c -o test"  
 Also run fines )
```

Now i have program, which uses openssl library. Here i am getting this error. If package is installed correctly then why error is coming at run time. Does the openssl function i have used have some dependencies which i missed  :---

Does openssl requires TOR ? this links says similar error caused  :--
https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-talk/2013-February/027252.html
https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/7215

md5.cpp :---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>

#include "md5.h"

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Construction/Destruction
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Cmd5::Cmd5( void )
{
    *m_szDigest = 0;
}

Cmd5::Cmd5( unsigned char *pstr )
{
    digest( pstr );
}

Cmd5::~Cmd5()
{

}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// digest
//

char *Cmd5::digest( unsigned char *pstr )
{

    EVP_MD_CTX mdctx;
  const EVP_MD *md;
    unsigned char md_value[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
  unsigned int md_len;

    OpenSSL_add_all_digests();

    md = EVP_get_digestbyname("md5");
    EVP_MD_CTX_init( &mdctx );
  EVP_DigestInit_ex( &mdctx, md, NULL );
  EVP_DigestUpdate( &mdctx, pstr, strlen( (const char *)pstr ) );
  EVP_DigestFinal_ex( &mdctx, md_value, &md_len );
  EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup( &mdctx );

    sprintf( m_szDigest, 
        "%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x\0",
        md_value[0],md_value[1],md_value[2],md_value[3],md_value[4],md_value[5],md_value[6],md_value[7],
        md_value[8],md_value[9],md_value[10],md_value[11],md_value[12],md_value[13],md_value[14],md_value[15] ); 


    return m_szDigest;

}
```

md5.h :---

```
#include <openssl/md5.h>

class Cmd5
{

public:

    /*!
        Default constructor
    */
    Cmd5( void );

    /*!
        Constructor
        @param pstr string to encrypt.
    */
    Cmd5( unsigned char *pstr );

    /*!
        Destructor
    */
    virtual ~Cmd5();

    /*!
        Perform MD5
        @param pstr string to encrypt.
        @return Encrypted data.
    */
    char *digest( unsigned char *pstr );

    /*!
        Perform MD5
        @return Encrypted data.
    */
    char *getDigest( void ) { return m_szDigest; };

private:

    /*!
        MD5 data
    */
    char m_szDigest[128];
};
```

Error :----

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ gdb vscpd
gdb: /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0)
gdb: /usr/local/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0)
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.4.1-debian
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "arm-linux-gnueabihf".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /home/pi/vscpd...done.


(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0xdd30: file vscpd.cpp, line 99.


(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/pi/vscpd 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
0x4025f7a0 in _armv7_neon_probe () from /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0



(gdb) bt
#0  0x4025f7a0 in _armv7_neon_probe () from /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
#1  0x4025bdc4 in OPENSSL_cpuid_setup () from /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
#2  0x4000f250 in ?? () from /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
#3  0xbefff858 in ?? ()
#4  0xbefff858 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
(gdb) debug2: client_check_window_change: changed
debug2: channel 0: request window-change confirm 0
(gdb)
```

Please suggest what is causing this error ?

Answer (score 4):

Try setting the environment variable OPENSSL_armcap=0 to disable that code.

The code in OPENSSL_cpuid_setup assumes it can trap SIGILL and continue if the instruction is unable to be performed.
You can just continue in gdb and the handler in OPENSSL_cpuid_setup should let it through - and that should function correctly.

You would normally (for this) use something like the following in gdb to let that happen:

handle SIGILL pass

Tim.

Comment: thanks ...handle SIGILL pass  -- command & -- continue works at gdb -- then i am able to step the program --- what is the commad to set the enviromental variable ... should it be in my .bashrc file ?

Comment: also is it possible to disable this error at the time when i .. compile openssl .. i.e at MAKE time .. ?